# Send GIF from iMessage by AppleScript

Tags: applescript, imessage

I know text message can be sent from AppleScript by "tell application 'Messages'", but if there is a method to send GIF by any AppleScript?
Many thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use application "Messages"

set gif to POSIX file "/Users/CK/Pictures/giphy.gif"
set [him] to buddies of service "E:someone@me.com" whose handle is "something"

send the gif to him
```

Comment: Is there any method to get the iMessage sending feedback? like: Delivered, Received, etc...

Comment: Just the usual feedback you get in the _Messages_ app, which usually displays a delivery report underneath the message.

Comment: I don't know how to get the feedback from AppleScript, could you please give me some demo code? thank you...

Comment: There is no feedback from AppleScript itself.  The "usual feedback" I was referring to is the delivery report one gets in _Messages_, both on the Mac and the iPhone, when a [message is delivered](https://i.imgur.com/KqBEngC.png?1), and then when it's read.